# .InlineShapes.AddPicture does not goes to bookmark.range

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I need to insert form Excel Vba Picture to Bookmark position behind text

```
 Dim iShape As Word.InlineShape, myShape As Word.Shape
 '.Bookmarks.Item("Sign_Sign").Range
 Set iShape = .Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(TemplatesShpSign_Sign, False, True, .Bookmarks.Item("Sign_Sign").Range)

 Set myShape = iShape.ConvertToShape
 With myShape
     .WrapFormat.Type = 5
 End With
```

No one of thoose is not working

```
Set iShape = .Bookmarks.Item("Sign_Sign").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(TemplatesShpSign_Sign, False, True, .Bookmarks.Item("Sign_Sign").Range)    
Set iShape = .Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(TemplatesShpSign_Sign, False, True, .Bookmarks.Item("Sign_Sign").Range)    
Set iShape = .Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(TemplatesShpSign_Sign, False, True)    
Set iShape = .Bookmarks.Item("Sign_Sign").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(TemplatesShpSign_Sign, False, True)
```

Picture always goes to the top of page, instead of bottom (bookmark position)

So how to place picture `wdWrapBehind` to bookmark position?

without `Set myShape = iShape.ConvertToShape` picture goes to right place but do not `wdWrapBehind`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Excel Picture to Word Bookmark macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684342/vba-excel-picture-to-word-bookmark-macro). Also: [Inserting a picture at a bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16152651/8112776)

Answer (score 0):

The first code you show works fine for me. It does wrap behind:

```
Sub InsertShapeBookmark()
    Dim iShape As Word.InlineShape, myShape As Word.Shape
    Dim rng As Word.Range

     Set rng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Item("Sign_Sign").Range
     Set iShape = rng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(TemplatesShpSign_Sign, False, True, rng)

     Set myShape = iShape.ConvertToShape
     With myShape
         .WrapFormat.Type = 5
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: For me, with the code I posted, the picture is positioned at the bookmark (top left of the picture is at the bookmark position).

Comment: As you do this for empty document probably, when document has many wraps and object after `.ConvertToShape` shape goes to top of page